# iOS: Why Change subview Frame when I Scrolled?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

How do I fix a subviews position on screen in UIScrollView ?
subview remove every time when I Scroll.

### I use this but blink subview.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{  
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:popupTag];   
    BOOL ISOPENED = FALSE;  
    if(vPopup.hidden == TRUE)  
    {  
        ISOPENED = FALSE;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        ISOPENED = TRUE;  
    }  
    [vPopup setHidden:YES];  
    if(ISOPENED)  
    {  
        double delayInSeconds = 0.01;  
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,delayInSeconds * USEC_PER_SEC);

        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

            vPopup.frame = CGRectMake(
                (btn.frame.origin.x + (btn.frame.origin.x * (scroll.zoomScale-1))) - ((popupW/2)-(scroll.zoomScale)),
                btn.frame.origin.y+(btn.frame.origin.y * (scroll.zoomScale-1)) - popupH,
                popupW, popupH);


            [vPopup setHidden:NO];  
        });  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you are hiding `vPopup` whenever the view scrolls (which can be 60 times per second) and then trying to show it after .01 seconds, after which it gets hidden again and shown .01 seconds afterwards.

Comment: I'm trying to always show vPopup whenever the view scrolls.

Comment: what a hell going on in this code... Why you don't try something not so expensive, f.e "scrollViewWillBeginDragging" or something like this to manage your view's visibility

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to put vPopup on scrollView's superView? Like self.view

In your code, you hide vPopup every time you scroll([vPopup setHidden:YES];)
but show it in `dispatch_after`, it takes times to show (>=delayInSeconds).

just remove `[vPopup setHidden:YES]` and `[vPopup setHidden:NO]` 
or put vPopup in scrollView's superView.

Comment: see this photo link -  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DQ0QfRNmjJ7G_8_9kyj69GbhkY_Nqsh25L6H84UFCvA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: may be the way you adjust vPopup.frame is wrong. if you do not change zoom scale, vPopup.frame should not change. but your code change the frame when zoom scale not change.